How to enable auto pairing for brackets in Ace Editor since setBehavioursEnabled is not working?
I'm trying to integrate Ace Editor with Angular 18 and have followed the guide here as well as this previous question. However, I'm facing an issue with auto-pairing brackets.
Despite setting setBehavioursEnabled(true) in my code, it doesn't seem to activate the bracket pairing feature. Interestingly, when I log the current behavior status using console.log(this.aceEditor.getBehavioursEnabled()), it returns true.
Could someone please help me figure out why the auto-pairing isn't working?
This is my code for the same
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import * as ace from "ace-builds";

@Component({
  selector: "app-ace-editor",
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl:'./ace-component.html',
  styles: [
    `
      .app-ace-editor {
        border: 2px solid #f8f9fa;
        box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
      }
      .toolbar {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .toolbar button,
      .toolbar select {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class AceEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("editor") private editor: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  private aceEditor: ace.Ace.Editor;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ace.config.set("fontSize", "14px");
    this.aceEditor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
    this.aceEditor.setBehavioursEnabled(true);
    this.aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/gruvbox_dark_hard");
    this.aceEditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
  }

  saveContent(): void {
    const content = this.aceEditor.getValue();
    console.log("Saved content:", content);
  }

  resetContent(): void {
    this.aceEditor.setValue("Is this ok", -1);
  }

  changeTheme(event: Event): void {
    const theme = (event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value;
    this.aceEditor.setTheme(theme);
  }

  changeMode(event: Event): void {
    const mode = (event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value;
    this.aceEditor.session.setMode(mode);
  }
}

I'm trying to display various utilities of Ace Editor in Angular using the following code, but the key functionalities like auto indentation and auto bracket pairing are missing which come under BehavioursEnabled part
